# Console does not show me the right value while using NSLog to show a placeholder of an Array

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I try to print the second placeholder of an Array in the console with the following code:

```
NSArray *europeTransaction = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:europeDollarTransaction,  [NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble: 200.00], nil];    

NSLog(@"I'm displaying the second placeholders value in the NSArray %.2f", europeTransaction [1]);
```

The console shows me a value of 0.00, while it should give me a value of 200.
What's wrong with the code?

Comment: NSLog(@"I'm displaying the second placeholders value in the NSArray %@", europeTransaction [1]);, use %@ for objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format specifier `%f` is used for floats, while you are passing an `NSNumber` instance. Either use the specifier `%@` or ask the `NSNumber` for its float representation:

```
NSLog(@"I'm displaying the second placeholders value in the NSArray %.2f",
      [europeTransaction[1] floatValue]);
```